# Compare some digits and print a result

Tags: php, mysql

Friends and all people. I have a problem with this script and can't find how to fix it. I have some phone numbers in DB. This numbers from different mobile operators with standard first digits like (code of operators) 38098 (phone number), 38066 (phone number), 38063 (phone number), 38099 (phone number). I need that script compare first digits and print what operators this number have (sorry for my bad english), for example: 38066 344-56-67 This user have Vodafone; 38098 344-56-67 This user have Kyivstar. So i do like this:

```
<? if ($mobile="38099") { ?>This user have Vodafone number
<? }else if ($mobile="38066") { ?>This user have Vodafone number
<? }else if ($mobile="38067") { ?>This user have Kyivstar number
<? } ?>
```

But this script do nohting (. It only work if phone number digits equil digits in "if" and "else if". Please help me to fix my problem

Comment: == - this is compare operator

Comment: you're assigning it to a variable.. use == for comparison

Comment: But even comparing won't work, since you are actually looking for the leading substring of the number. Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php  And most likely you will run into issues with numbers being formatted in different ways...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are assigning, not comparing, you need to compare values here.

something like:

```
if(variable == value)
```

This is called, `if ($mobile="38099")` assigning the values, you can't compare the values like that, = sign is use for assigning.

For comparing, you can use `==`, which is use to compare values, either equal or not, something like:

```
if ($mobile == "38099")
```

If you want to compare values and data type together than you can use `===` sign, which will compare the values either equal or not along with dataType checking.

*Manual will help you to understand more: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php*

Answer (score 1):

i think if your example is really like it " 38066 344-56-67 " you should use

```
$nra = explode(" ", $mobile);
```

and test the first index in the new table like

```
if($nra[0] == "38099")
{
     echo"This user have Vodafone number";
}
else if($nra[0] == "38066").....
```

and use `==` instead of "=" for the comparison

Comment: not working ? have you get an error or it doesn't print what you want ? I forget ";" after the echo

Comment: @MacBooc Page just have white background anв that's it!

Comment: ok my answer still do the same that Arun but if you get your answer it's ok

Comment: i forget a space too in the else if statement ... my bad

Comment: @MacBooc Your script is brilliant too. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$test = '38066 344-56-67'; 
$mobile = substr($test, 0, 5);
if ($mobile=="38099") { 
  echo "This user have Vodafone number";
}
else if ($mobile=="38066") 
{ 
  echo "This user have Vodafone number";
}
else if ($mobile=="38067") 
{ 
  echo "This user have Kyivstar number";
} 
?>
```

Comment: i am editing your answer, your answer looks fine with substr, just add == sign in condition